# NodeJS child_process or nextTick or setTimeout for long waiting task?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, node-modules

I have seen some questions about **sending response immediately** and **run CPU intensive tasks**.

My case is my node application **depends on third party service responses** so the process flow is

> 1. Node receives request and authenticates with third-party service
> 2. Send response to user after authentication
> 3. Do some tasks that needs responses from third party service
> 4. Save the results to database

In my case there is **no CPU intensive tasks** and no need to give results of additional tasks to the user but node needs to wait for responses from third-party service. I have to do multiple req/res to/from the third-party service after the authentication to complete the task.

How can I achieve this situation?

I have seen some workarounds with child_process, nextTick and setTimeOut.

Ultimately I want to send response immediately to user and do tasks related to that user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `callThirdParty(); res.send(something)` This should call your third party without waiting and `res` to user and close the connection, (theoretically). Some code how you tried might help

Comment: i need to do_some_tasks() after sending res.send() without waiting to finish do_some_tasks()

Answer (score 1):

```
elsewhere in your code
function do_some_tasks() { //... }

// route function
(req, res) => {
  // call some async task
  do_some_tasks()
  // if the above is doing some asynchronous task, next function should be called immediately without waiting, question is is it so?
  res.send()
}

// if your do_some_tasks() is synchronous func, the you can do
// this function call will be put to queue and executed asynchronously
setImmediate(() => {
  do_some_tasks()
})
// this will be called in the current iteration
res.send(something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just writing a very general code block here:

```
var do_some_tasks = (req, tp_response) => {
    third_party_tasks(args, (err, result)=<{
        //save to DB
    });
}

var your_request_handler = (req,res) => {
    third_party_auth(args, (tp_response)=>{
        res.send();
        //just do your tasks here
        do_some_tasks(req, tp_response);
    });
}
```